# Anaconda Installation Failed on macOS Ventura

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, macos-ventura

I am trying to install Anaconda on my new MacBook which has Ventura 13.1 installed.

I am installing only for myself and the installation fails.

Can someone please help?

**Edit 1**

I have followed [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#the-installation-failed-message-when-running-a-pkg-installer-on-osx) link but I do not see that.

**Edit 2**

As it was a new setup, I erased the disk and was able to reinstall it.

[image]

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept that to help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was a new setup, I erased the disk and was able to reinstall it.

When I installed again, it asked that the installer wants access to Download folder.

Earlier, I may not have allowed it.

This time I did and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Directly running the [sh script](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to erase disc to solve this problem.
I made the same mistake, not allowed to access at the first time so the installation failed. I deleted the installation package and re-downladed it but the problem is still there. So go to system preferences, click on Security & Privacy>Files and Folders and turn on the "allow the applications below to access" switch. Then download Anaconda again. It works!